# How to maintain a unique session for all html and jsp pages in Eclipse using servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, session, servlets

I am new to servlet. I am creating a small dynamic web application. I want to create a login and logout module, through which the other HTML or JSP page can only be accessed if proper login is made. I have created a simple login and logout HTML and its servlet with the help of some online source. But what if I want that after successful login only the user can access other HTML or JSP pages. And the same JSP or HTML page might not get accessed by directly hitting on URL web address.

In the below project structure, there is some JSP and HTML page. Suppose I don't want to let a user to directly open ola.html and ola_create.jsp without proper login, then how should I make it work. Please look below for my project structure:

[image]

Below is the code for the servlet:

LoginServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;  
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                    throws ServletException, IOException {  
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();  
        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);  

        String name=request.getParameter("name");  
        String password=request.getParameter("password");  

        if(password.equals("admin123")){  
        //response.sendRedirect("ola.html");
       // out.print("Welcome, "+name);  
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
        session.setAttribute("name",name);  
        }  
        else{  
            out.print("Sorry, username or password error!");  
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);  
        }  
        out.close();  
    }  
}
```

LogoutServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;  
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {  
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                                throws ServletException, IOException {  
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();  

            request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);  

            HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
            session.invalidate();  

            out.print("You are successfully logged out!");  

            out.close();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Check session is valid in your jsp's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Servlet filter, in this case, .It is mainly used to perform filtering tasks such as conversion, logging, compression, encryption and decryption, input validation etc.

So basically it is like a validation layer before you can access your resources which can be a servlet, JSP or HTML page.so for example, if you create a filter with url-mapping /hello, so for every request to /hello,first filter will be executed. You can validate whether the user is logged in or not in this filter if your validation fails user won't be allowed to access the /hello request.

you can define something like this in web.xml file.

```
<filter>  
<filter-name>f1</filter-name>  
<filter-class>MyFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>  

<filter-mapping>  
<filter-name>f1</filter-name>  
<url-pattern>/ola</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

This is how you define your filter

```
 import java.io.IOException;  
    import java.io.PrintWriter;  

    import javax.servlet.*;  

    public class MyFilter implements Filter{  

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}  

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  

        PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();  
        out.print("filter is invoked before");  

     String user=request.getParameter("username");
      if(user=="admin"){

        chain.doFilter(req, resp);//sends request to next resource  

       }     
else  {
 out.print("You are not authorized to view this page");  
}

        }  
        public void destroy() {}  
    }
```

appendix-

- https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-filter
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5GfmTUHAnM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=preCXrKFISg